# Resizing views on orientation change

Tags: android, layout, graph, orientation

I'm new to android development(v 4.0, API 14) and stuck in implementing orientation change.

I've added the following line in manifest file
`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">`

But it looks like `screenSize` parameter is not working so I have to manually write these two methods:

```
public void ChangetoLandscape() {
    ed.setTranslationX(300.0f);
    btnindex.setTranslationX(300.0f);
    btngainer.setTranslationX(300.0f);
    btnloser.setTranslationX(300.0f);
    lsym.setTranslationX(200.0f);
    ltable.setTranslationX(300.0f);
    tv1.setTranslationX(290.0f);
    tv2.setTranslationX(300.0f);
    tv4.setTranslationX(300.0f);

    mySimpleXYPlot.setScaleX(3.0f);
    mySimpleXYPlot.setScaleY(0.8f);
    mySimpleXYPlot.setPlotMarginLeft(50.0f);
    mySimpleXYPlot.setTranslationX(60.0f);
    mySimpleXYPlot.setTranslationY(-70.0f);

    sv1.setTranslationY(-80.0f);
}

public void ChangetoPortrait() {

//NOTE THAT IF I DON'T WRITE BELOW CODE,
//SWITCHING TO PORTRAIT MODE AFTER LANDSCAPE MODE RUINS THE WHOLE LAYOUT.
        ed.setTranslationX(-1.0f);
        btnindex.setTranslationX(-1.0f);
        btngainer.setTranslationX(-1.0f);
        btnloser.setTranslationX(-1.0f);
        lsym.setTranslationX(-1.0f);
        ltable.setTranslationX(-1.0f);
        tv1.setTranslationX(-1.0f);
        tv2.setTranslationX(-1.0f);
        tv4.setTranslationX(-1.0f);
        mySimpleXYPlot.setScaleX(1.0f);
        mySimpleXYPlot.setScaleY(1.0f);
        mySimpleXYPlot.setPlotMarginLeft(1.0f);
        mySimpleXYPlot.setTranslationX(-1.0f);
        mySimpleXYPlot.setTranslationY(-1.0f);

        sv1.setTranslationY(-1.0f);
}
```

.

I'm using RelativeLayout, so I've to manually translate each view to specified position on orientation change.

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/MainLayout">"
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search"
    android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:cursorVisible="false" >
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnindex"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Index" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/txt1"
    android:textSize="12dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btngainer"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Gainer" 
    android:layout_below="@id/txt1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnindex"
    android:textSize="12dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnloser"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Loser" 
    android:layout_below="@id/txt1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btngainer"
    android:textSize="12dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textColor="#00ff00"
    android:text="SYMBOL"/> <!-- 2 similar textviews -->

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/ltable"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt1">
</ListView>
    
<com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
android:id="@+id/mySimpleXYPlot"
android:layout_width="140dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnindex"
title="Index"/>

<ScrollView android:id="@+id/sv1"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_marginTop="250dp">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/tv1"
android:text="Scrollview Item 1"/> <!-- 5 similar textviews -->
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

.

1. But as showed in below screenshot, in landscape mode, graph which is plotted using `android plot` is not getting properly displayed. The reason behind this is I've used `setScaleX()` method bcoz `setWidth()` is not available. I don't want graph to look stretched. Instead it's width should be increased.
2. ScrollView is getting displayed properly in `portrait mode` but in `landscape mode`, it is not visivle according to it's height which is 100dp.

[image: ScreenShot]

---

Edit: After changing `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` to
`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`,
I get this when I switch to landscape mode:

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: There are a couple of alarming things here.

When you say that "screenSize parameter is not working", what do you mean? Are you overriding onConfigChanged() and calling these methods from onConfigChanged()? If you are, this is exactly what is supposed to happen.

Secondly, you seem to be using the RelativeLayout more like an AbsoluteLayout. I'd strongly suggest that you readup on the RelativeLayout tutorials. If implemented correctly, you'd not have to do any of the translations. Everything should be taken care of.

Comment: Continuing..
Thirdly, it looks like you are looking for different layouts for potrait and landscape modes. If this is true, you should consider using layout-land and layout-potrait.

Comment: @VikramBodicherla 1.) I'm overriding onConfigChanged() but i'm calling `ChangetoLandscape()` and `ChangetoPortrait()` methods in it. **Nothing** related to screenSize. 2.)Can you explain in brief, what I'm doing **wrong** with `RelativeLayout`. 3) I tried using `layout-land` and `layout-potrait`, but it **re-creates** the activity, which is exactly I **don't** want..

Comment: i got this : **LinearLayout means you can align views one by one. 
Relative Layout means based on relation of views. Absolute Layout means you have to give exact position where the view should be..** But still, what am I doing wrong in my xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `LayoutParams` to place the graph at appropriate location instead of `scale()` function.